# static_cast for user defined types

Tags: c++

Is it possible and why one would want to do it?

```
class Foo;
class Bar;

......

Foo foo;
Bar bar = static_cast<Bar>(foo);
```

Normally static_cast is used with numeric types and pointers, but can it work with user defined data types, a.k.a classes?

Comment: Yes, it can work, but you also have to know how to use it - here's a start on what each cast does in C++: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Bar bar = static_cast<Bar>(foo);
```

This cast will fail. `Foo` and `Bar` are incompatible types, unless atleast one of the following is true:

- `Foo` is derived from `Bar`, Or
- `Bar` has a constructor that takes `Foo`, Or
- `Foo` has a user-defined conversion to `Bar`.

The bigger question here is not whether it will cast successfully or not. The bigger and the actual question should be: what do you want to get out of such cast? Why would  you want to do such a thing in the first place? What is it supposed to do? I mean, how would the `Bar` object be initialized from `Foo` object?

The sensible way to convert one type to another is one of the following ways:

Either define `Foo` as:

```
class Foo : public Bar
{
   //...
};
```

Or define `Bar` as:

```
class Bar
{
  public: 
       Bar(const Foo &foo); //define this constructor in  Bar!
};
```

Or provide a conversion function in `Foo` as:

```
class Foo
{
  public: 
       operator Bar(); //provide a conversion function Foo to Bar!
};
```

Comment: Or will it fail? What if `Foo` implements a conversion operator to `Bar`?

Comment: Probably you want to use the "explicit" keyword when you do this to prevent accidental casts.

Answer (score 11):

Here's the rule:

The expression `static_cast<T>(e)` is valid if and only if the following variable definition is valid

```
T x(e);
```

where `x` is some invented variable.

So, in general, two unrelated types cannot be cast to one another. However, if one type is derived from the other, or when one defines a conversion function to the other, or has a constructor taking a single argument of the other type - in these cases static_cast will be well-defined.

Does it ever make sense? For example, if T defines a constructor that takes a single U and the constructor is `explicit` then `static_cast<T>(e)` where e is of type U would make perfect sense

Comment: It especially makes sense in generic code, for instance if T could be a user-defined type but also could be a built-in type. Then if you wrote `(T(e))` instead of `static_cast<T>(e)` (extra parens to ensure it's not a definition of `e`), then that's a C-style cast equivalent to `((T)e)`, and for built-in types there's a risk of it turning into a `reinterpret_cast`.